# How to change the color of sys.stdin synchronously?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple program that can be used as a theme for Python.

The stdin's color is white, stdout's color is green and stderr's color is red.

The program works fine but also what i want to do is, when the user type a keyword like **"def"**, this keyword's color should be changed as like as typing **"def"** in Vim.

I thought to use a keylogger in order to catch the keyboard. But still i haven't found a useful way to change the keyword colors synchronously.

Please take a look at the codes and give me an idea.

Any help is much appreciated.

Codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import colorama

CODE = ""
SIZE = 0
TAB = " " * 4

colorama.init(autoreset=False)
sys.stdout.write(colorama.Fore.WHITE)

while True:
    if SIZE >= 1:
        LINE = input("... {}".format(TAB * SIZE))
        CODE += "{}{}\n".format(TAB * SIZE, LINE)
        if LINE == '':
            if SIZE == 0:
                try:
                    sys.stdout.write(colorama.Fore.GREEN)
                    exec(CODE)
                    sys.stdout.write(colorama.Fore.WHITE)
                except BaseException as ERR:
                    sys.stderr.write("{}{}\n".format(colorama.Fore.RED, ERR))
                    sys.stdout.write(colorama.Fore.WHITE)
                CODE = ""
                SIZE = 0
            else:
                SIZE -= 1
                continue

        elif LINE.endswith(":"):
            SIZE += 1
        else:
            continue
    else:
        LINE = input(">>> {}".format(TAB * SIZE))
        CODE += "{}{}\n".format(TAB * SIZE, LINE)
        if not LINE.endswith(":"):
            if LINE == "exit()" or LINE == "quit()":
                break
            elif LINE == "clear()":
                os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
                CODE = ""
            try:
                sys.stdout.write(colorama.Fore.GREEN)
                exec(CODE)
                sys.stdout.write(colorama.Fore.WHITE)
            except BaseException as ERR:
                sys.stderr.write("{}{}\n".format(colorama.Fore.RED, ERR))
                sys.stdout.write(colorama.Fore.WHITE)
            CODE = ""
            SIZE = 0
        else:
            SIZE += 1
```

[image: https://i.hizliresim.com/vJ48Jv.png]

Comment: it is not so difficulty, I'll try when my pc is at hand

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will be waiting.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong. I missunderstand your mind. I thought that you want to `print colorfully`，but you want to change the `REPL`. Why not try ipython?

Comment: Maybe，`print` will be ok if redirect IO. I have custom colorful print using `\33[m xxx \33[m` or so.(Forgive my poor english)

Comment: i will try IPython. I have no problem with changing the color of stdout. But changing the color of input() is not easy as i thought. Maybe there's a simple way or there's a module which i haven't known. Do you know any module for this operation?

Comment: Recently i have run IPython, as you said, the keywords of Python are changed synchronously. But can't we change the colors of stdin in Python by modifying the above codes?

Comment: Maybe, you should modify `the CPython source code of Python Interpreter` to modify the stdin format.  I'm not  good at this.

Comment: Maybe.I need to search for this. Thank you very much. By the way if you find a solution, would you like to share with me?

Comment: Yeah, i will share with you if I find it.

Comment: Thanks, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I finish my terminal as follow. Looks pretty!  `O(∩_∩)O哈哈哈~`

[image]

To highlight `def`, I do this operation:

```
## Replace "def" with "colorful def"
if line.endswith(":") and "def " in line:
    sys.stderr.write("\x1b[1A\x1b[2K" + tag + line.replace("def ","\033[92mdef\033[0m ")+"\n")
```

Comment: What i wanted to do is not colorizing sys.stdout or sys.stderr. And the problem was solved. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813639/8016168

Comment: Yeah, I do replace the last line with `color-coded keyword`. Although It is not so elegant, it works pretty good for me. And I make it powerful by repeating keywords using regular expression and colorizing sys.stdout / sys.stderr  using custom colorful log class. In other words, `I make it just using  built-in libraries(sys, os, re, time), without other third-party libraries`. By the way, thanks for your original code that gives me inspiration.