# How to use pygments with readline to colorize the input text according to the tokens?

Tags: python, readline, pygments

I want to develop a Python theme which executes Python codes and which colorize the tokens in input() while users typing some text.

Recently I have started to learn readline and pygments.

I can add keyword tokens to the tab completion. Also i can colorize the stdout text with pygments highlight function.

But still i can't colorize the tokens in input().

Is there anyone to give me an idea to do what i want?

The codes below are from an example application.

```
import readline
from pygments.token import Token
from pygments.style import Style
from pygments.lexers import Python3Lexer
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import Terminal256Formatter
import keyword


class Completer:
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.words = words
        self.prefix = None
        self.match = None

    def complete(self, prefix, index):
        if prefix != self.prefix:
            self.match = [i for i in self.words if i.startswith(prefix)]
            self.prefix = prefix
        try:
            return self.match[index]
        except IndexError:
            return None


class MyStyle(Style):
    styles = {
        Token.String: '#ansiwhite',
        Token.Number: '#ansired',
        Token.Keyword: '#ansiyellow',
        Token.Operator: '#ansiyellow',
        Token.Name.Builtin: '#ansiblue',
        Token.Literal.String.Single: '#ansired',
        Token.Punctuation: '#ansiwhite'
    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    code = highlight("print('hello world')", Python3Lexer(), Terminal256Formatter(style=MyStyle))
    readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
    readline.set_completer(Completer(keyword.kwlist).complete)
    print(code)
    while True:
        _input = input(">>> ")
        if _input == "quit":
            break
        else:
            print(_input)
```

And this is the screenshot of how this application works. As you can see, when the program starts, a "print('hello world')" string is highlighted with pygments. And after that pressing the TAB 2 times gives the keywords.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with the below codes:

```
from pygments.lexers import Python3Lexer
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.layout.lexers import PygmentsLexer
text = prompt('>>> ', lexer=PygmentsLexer(Python3Lexer))
```